# can we retrieve certain number of JSON records using $.ajax call?

Tags: json, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am calling a Web API through $.ajax() call. And I am getting the result set in JSON format. Is there any way we can retrieve X number of records?

Comment: The server must support doing so.

Comment: Does the web service you are calling provide a parameter to limit the returned amount, e.g. paging support?

Comment: That's entirely up to the API you're calling. If it's an API you've written, then add a record limit parameter. If it's someone else's API and they DON'T allow limiting record counts, then submit a feature request. There's nothing you can do on your client to limit how much data comes back, other than filtering it AFTER it's been received.

Comment: I applied slice function on the JSON array which I was receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Slice function to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do that in your php-file before your ajax call, or in javascript after the call. Pretty sure you can't do that with $.ajax() directly.